# Only a part of my screen is used as the display. Rest is just black

Tags: graphics, screen

[This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPzOr.jpg)
[Picture of the xrandr command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSavQ.png)

Initially it worked okay. Just a few days back this happened suddenly.
**Please help me fix this issue.**

> Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1024 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
>   LVDS1 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
>      1366x768       60.0 +
>      1360x768       59.8     60.0
>      1280x720       60.0
>      1024x768       60.0* 
>      1024x576       60.0
>      960x540        60.0
>      800x600        60.3     56.2
>      864x486        60.0
>      640x480        59.9
>      720x405        60.0
>      680x384        60.0
>      640x360        60.0
>   VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
>   VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
>   VGA-1-2 connected 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
>      1024x768       60.0* 
>      800x600        60.3     56.2
>      848x480        60.0
>      640x480        59.9
>   HDMI-1-1 disconnected
>     1024x768 (0x44)   65.0MHz
>           h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock   48.4KHz
>           v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock   60.0Hz
>     800x600 (0x45)   40.0MHz
>           h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock   37.9KHz
>           v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock   60.3Hz
>     800x600 (0x46)   36.0MHz
>           h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock   35.2KHz
>           v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock   56.2Hz
>     640x480 (0x48)   25.2MHz
>           h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
>           v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock   59.9Hz

Comment: Please add the output of xrandr (run from a terminal).

Comment: @Jacob Vlijim  uploaded it!

Comment: Thanks! Could you simply copy the output textually and paste it into your question?

Comment: I have to run, will look into it tomorrow if no one answered yet by then. It looks however you set your screens mirrored, wich forces your laptop screen into a size that does not cover the whole screen. (1024x768). Use System Settings > Displays to change.

Answer (score 0):

Your display is set to a "square" (4:3 ratio) resolution.
Open monitor settings and change it to "widescreen' (16:9 ratio) resolution.

When the VGA is plugged in, go into monitor settings and set it to extend desktop instead of mirroring.